# Get transformed asset URL in controller

Tags: image-transforms

I want to return JSON with some asset URLs, but i want these URLs to be transformed asset URLs.

Is there some way for me to get the asset transformed URL in the controller? Will the assets be automatically transformed or i need to somehow do it manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do it from PHP nearly idential to how you'd do it from Twig... by passing in the Asset Transform's handle to [AssetFileModel's](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel) [`getUrl()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel#getUrl-detail) method.

Twig:

```
{% set asset = craft.assets.id(1).first() %}

{% if asset %}
    {{ asset.getUrl('myTransform') }}
{% endif %}
```

PHP:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset);
$criteria->id = 1;
$asset = $criteria->first();

if ($asset)
{
    $url = $asset->getUrl('myTransform');
}
```

Comment: yep thats the way, thank you very much :)

Comment: How to do the same in Craftcms 3.

Comment: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30264/get-transformed-asset-url-in-controller-of-module-while-using-eager-loading